# How to configure ChromeDriver environment variable in Windows 32-bit machine

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

In Windows 7 32-bit machine, i am facing problem configuring chromedriver environment variable path:

I have downloaded chromedriver.exe binary and save in this path "D:\softies\chromedriverV2.28.exe"

Then in System environment variable, i have added this path in "path" environment variable.

Then i opened command prompt and entered chromedriver and hit enter
I am getting "

> 'chromedriver' is not recognized as an internal or external
>   command,operable program or batch file.

"

But i followed the same steps in Windows 7 64-bit machine, then i am able to start chromedriver.

So can someone help me how to configure this in Window 7 32-bit machine?

Comment: Post output of commands 'set path' and 'where chromedriverV2.28.exe' here.

Answer (score 3):

Rename chromedriverv2.28.exe to chromedriver.exe, check that your path you have added 'D:\softies\'